# CodeIgniter 4 findAll empty

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-4

Please can someone help with My Model. I want to get users from table users in database (SQL Server) with model builder.

Example:

```
 $cred= new CredModel();
 $cred->select('*');
 $list=$cred->findAll();
```

Model returns array(0). I use SQL Server with SQLSRV58 installed on windows.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: The sql server version is 2016

also using raw query mode returns empty array:


       $ db = \ Config \ Database :: connect ();
    
       $ query = $ db-> query ("SELECT * FROM users");
       $ results = $ query-> getResult ();
       
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($ db);

echo "</pre>"; to die();


using "paginate" or "find" of the model builder is ok

Comment: Please provide the attributs of your CredModel class. The result of `findAll()` relies on them.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the table name with `from`

```
$cred = new CredModel();
$cred->select('*');
$cred->from('users');
$list = $cred->findAll();
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the table with a `from` function if you declared the `$table` attribut in your model